# Build a program on raspberry PI windows 10 IOT

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10

Can i build my program and run it when the raspberry Boot up? Without using Debug stuff with visual studio?
I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3 with Windows 10 IOT.

Answer (score 0):

After you [deployed your app to Windows iot core](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/appdeployment) device. There are two methods to set your app running at boot up(start up):

1. [Use command line](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/commandlineutils):

`IotStartup add headed [MyApp] //adds headed applications that match pattern MyApp. Pattern must match only one application.`

`IotStartup add headless [Task1] //adds headless applications that match pattern Task1`

2. [Use device portal](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/deviceportal):

> Under the STARTUP column, you can select as many background
>   applications to start by default, but can only set one foreground
>   application.

[image]